# When does SQL Server evaluate where clauses in a view?

Tags: sql-server, view, where-clause, evaluate

I have a view which contains a query that can return a large amount of data. Then, into my Delphi application, I call to this view with a `WHERE` clause to filter the results I want.

So my question is: when will SQL server evaluate this where clause? I mean, if I have the next view called `getSales` (it's just an example):

`select * from sales`

and the query has:

`select * from getSales where customer = :id`

What will SQL server do?

1. Will it search directly for the sales that has the provided id customer?
2. **Or** will it search all sales and filter it by ID customer **after** get the results?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will apply the where clause to the base data using any appropriate indexes that are available - i.e. it will be efficient and search directly for the sales that have the customer id once there is an index on customer id.  Without an index it would potentially perform a table scan.

Comment: In pre-SQL Server 2008, there may be performance problems due to [predicate pushing](http://jahaines.blogspot.ie/2010/03/performance-tuning-101-what-you-will_17.html), but later versions should more or less work as expected.

Comment: In the query I want to execute, the parameter fields are part of the primary key of the table (the PK is a combination of the customer id and the order id of the sale; and the filter of the view depends only of the customer)

Comment: It should use the primary key/index.  Run the query in SSMS and check the execution plan to be sure.